# AWS Network Load Balancer: failure connection when the source and the target are the same

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-elb

I have an EC2 instance which has two applications installed and configured:

- App #1 runs on post 8001
- App #2 runs on port 8002

Apps answer perfectly if I use url:

- http://sample-ec2-(public/private)-ip:8001
- http://sample-ec2-(public/private)-ip:8002

I add a Network Load Balancer with 2 target groups and 2 listener rules. Both of the target groups are pointing to the same EC2 instance. Target type I selected "instance", because only this type may used in autoscaling groups.

Apps answer perfectly by url, if I do request from another instances:

- http://network-load-balancer-dns:8001
- http://network-load-balancer-dns:8002

But my applications can't do request to each other from same instance.

```
# curl --trace-ascii - http://network-load-balancer-dns:8001
== Info:   Trying NLB-ADDERSS...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
```

How may solve this problem?

Comment: Are the instances in private subnet?

Comment: Yes, the instance in a private subnet

Comment: And the "another instance" which works is also in the same private subnet or public?

Comment: Yes, in the same private subnet.